# What type of machine learning do you recommend to use to detect a object that has a lot of sizes

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, kinect, surf

Well I am doing a project in which I want to recognize a object using Kinect and open cv!! But that object have a lot of different sizes!!I could take a lot of photos of that object!! my question is What type of machine learning do you recommend to use in this case and what type of features detection like SURF or others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SIFT descriptor then you will get a descriptor matrix of `1 x 64` and similarly if you use  SURF descriptor then you will get a descriptor matrix of `1 x 128`. So, for each image you will get a matrix either of size `1 x 64` or `1 x 128`. Then you use this single row matrices as input vectors for SVM training.

Comment: ooohh yap!!Let me see!! then, if I have 5 images I will have 5 matrix of 1x28 and then I have 5 input vector fo SVM training right??

Comment: I will do!One question more!!Explain me about labes in SVM!!I redad that labes are classes!In my case are It is object and isn´t!But I read that I can put labels for each element of vector!I am confused!please explan me that and I give you a vote in another anwser!!

Comment: For each input image/sample/vector, you have to tell the SVM what is its class. If you have only two classes, for example you just want to classify the images into Class Car and class Not-Car then you can assing label 1 with the input samples which have car in it...and you can assign label -1 to samples which doesn't have car in it....I would suggest you to use google for such trivial questions...Please try to explore yourself as much as possible.

Comment: So I must train SVM wih positive images and negatives imgaes??

Comment: mmm well I have 1000 positives imgaes now!!Is there any problem if I eliminate background of positives images and leave only object that I want to recognize?

Comment: no...train with the object only....and now please do not ask how to remove the background.

Comment: hey.If I use images of apples in order to be recognized by SVM , so if images contain 2 or more apple SVM tell that images contain apples?? or onnly recognize one object inside images

Answer (score 0):

You can use SIFT which is scale invariant. I have used SIFT/SURF alongwith SVM in one of my application where i had to classify the objects and i got very good results. With SIFT, the change in size and orientation would not be any problem.

Comment: You said SIFT/SURF can you explain me what is the differences in my case??

Comment: you can use either and check the performance in your case....the whole code will remain the same...you will just need to replace SIFT by SURF and vice versa.

Comment: Greaat!! I have another question!! Can you explain me "With SIFT, the change in size and orientation would not be any problem."?  What are you talking about!!!

Comment: Size: there won't be any problem if the object appears bigger/smaller.  Orientation: there won't be any problem is the object gets rotated.

Comment: And how about color!!If I have a object that is the same in morning and have another color in night!!How can I deal with that??

Comment: SIFT/SURF are used with grayScale images and the results are good. I would suggest you to start working. It will work !!!

Comment: Yes I know but I think that I should equalize histogram before or what do you think?

Comment: you can try different possibilities. I just loaded the color images, converted to gray, used SIFT/SURF and got results which were quite good. So, may be you can start it in that way and can add things later on to improve results.

Comment: hey.If I use images of apples in order to be recognized by SVM , so if images contain 2 or more apple SVM tell that images contain apples?? or onnly recognize one object inside images